# BigQuery regex extraction

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract a sample_type field from an URL that works in regular regex, but is not working in BigQuery

This regex works fine in the online tool at regex101.com: `(?<=sample_type=)[\w_]+` to extract the word apple, but does not seem to apply to BQ. What is the correct way to get what is after sample_type for BQ?

`SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('asdfasdfjsklfjasdf/info?sample_type=apple', r'sample_type=\w_+')`

Comment: Note that `\w` also match `_` and `\w_+` matches a single word char followed by 1 or more underscores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `sample_type=(\w+)` as a regexpbelow as in below example

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('asdfasdfjsklfjasdf/info?sample_type=apple', r'sample_type=(\w+)')
```